# Can you write a sql statement without spaces between keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security

I am trying to do SQL Injection testing but I am currently testing a command line that separates parameters by spaces, so I'm trying to write a sql statement without any spaces.  I've gotten it down to:

`create table"aab"("id"int,"notes"varchar(100))`

But I cannot figure out how to get rid of the space between CREATE and TABLE. The same would apply obviously for DROP and TABLE, etc.

Does anyone have any ideas?  This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2014.  Thanks!

[Update]: We are evaluating a third party product for vulnerabilities. I am not doing this to test my own code for weaknesses.

Comment: You can put in some other white space character (say, newline), but there needs to be a separator.

Comment: Why not simply use prepared statements? That also saves you from sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, you have to check every argument to make sure they are as intended.

If they are supposed to be numbers, make sure they are numbers, is they are supposed to be a string that may contain specific caracters (like ' or ,) you should escape them when executing the request.

There should be a dedicated mechanism in your programmation langage to take care of hat (like PreparedStatement in Java)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Julien!  I should have been more clear. I understand how to develop to protect against SQL injection attacks. We are evaluating a third party product to see if it is vulnerable to SQL Injection and the program is written in erlang. So before I go digging through tons of code in a language I haven't used before, I am trying to kick the tires and see if I can break it.

Answer (score 6):

You can write comments between lines instead of spaces in many cases. So /**/ instead of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible to write some pretty elaborate statements without spaces.

Here is one.

```
select'asdf'as[asdf]into[#MyTable]
```

You can even do things like execute sp_executesql without spaces.

```
exec[sp_executesql]N'select''asdf''as[asdf]into[#MyTable]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also using brackets () for every functions without spaces

`SELECT(COUNT(id))FROM(users)where(id>5)`